# Can I copy my partition onto another partition on the same disk?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

Sorry if this has been answered, I see a lot of information about moving to a different drive but not same drive/new partition.

[My drive is partitioned like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygpe5.png)

The /sdb2 is Windows 10 which I just shrunk to create unallocated, the partition all the way on the right with ~25gb is Ubuntu. In between those is a pesky fat32/boot/efi(?). I'm not 100% sure what it does but it seems like it may be necessary for booting, it has 1mb of it's 512mb allocation filled.

I just want Ubuntu to have more space. I'm totally new to partitioning drives, it seems that even if I was able to delete the boot/efi safely, that moving the Ubuntu partition into the free space would cause trouble (as it's preceding space?).

So my plan was to:
-Boot into Ubuntu "trial" via USB
-Copy my current Ubuntu partition onto the 100gb space
-Just accept the 25gb as lost.

Would this work? Could it cause problems with my data? Is there a better way? I'm really looking for the path of least resistance as I'd just like to get back to work, but I also want to be cautious about how I proceed with messing with disk stuff considering everything I know is from googling I did today.

Comment: There is really no difference if you copy a partition to a different HDD or the same one. It should work, and it could cause problems with my data. Backup all important data first. Not sure what you mean by better way, there is no way to learn things without some effort. You'll also need to take care of UUID and GRUB to make the new partition bootable.

Comment: By better way I mean better than my plan as detailed in the 5th paragraph- just above where I said that.

Comment: Is drive MBR (msdos) or gpt partitioned? ESP is essential for UEFI booting, but if Windows on MBR drive, then it is booting in BIOS mode. Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: There are infinite number of ways to modify my plan. In fact, I've added to it quite a bit already - backup, UUID, grub. However, different is not always better or worse, especially for someone you know nothing about.